# Using html values from <pre></pre> to a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Consider the following snippet.

```
<div class="original" contenteditable="true">
<pre contenteditable="true">&lt;p class="text-centre">
&lt;/bHello World>&lt;/b>
&lt;/p></pre>
</div>
```

Then I have another div as follows

```
<div class="replace">

</div>
```

As you can see in the first div I am making it editable where users can style their own `h1, p, tables` etc but for now I am just showing `<p>`.

I have a button which on click I want the `<p>` from the first div with class `original` to be placed in the second div with class `replace` but taking the styling into account i.e. the above `<p>` should be displayed as - **Hello World**

With my jQuery I just replaces the value from one div to the another

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.test').click(function () {
            var replaced = $('.original').html();
            $('.replace').html(replaced);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: XSS welcome ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix this, use `text()` to retrieve the value from `.original` so that the HTML entities are encoded properly, then use `html()` to set the content in the `.replace` div, like this:

```js
$('.test').click(function() {
  var replaced = $('.original').text();
  $('.replace').html(replaced);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="original" contenteditable="true">
  <pre contenteditable="true">&lt;p class="text-centre">
&lt;b&gt;Hello World&lt;/b>
&lt;/p></pre>
</div>

<button class="test">Go</button>

<div class="replace"></div>
```

Note that I amended the HTML in the `pre` tag as it was not valid in your question.

Comment: Thanks for this. Will a similar principle work for tables, headers etc? If possible can you provide a small example of how it will work for a table please

Comment: It's exactly the same. Any HTML you write in the `<pre>` tag will be populated in the DOM. One thing to be aware of is that you may be vulnerable to XSS, so make sure you sanitise any HTML/JS before appending it to the DOM

Answer (score 0):

This might not work for all applications, but if the positioning doesn't mess up, you could have the div replace and the pre in the same block or same div, set the thing to replace as display:none, and then add css for:

```
.thingtoclick:focus{
    display:block;
}
.thingtoclick:focus .thingtodisappear{
display:none;
}
```